# Why does `rsnapshot` repeatedly request password?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, rsnapshot

My server configuration file has several `backup` lines that sync changes from my laptop's home directory. Since reinstalling the server OS (OpenSuse), `rsnapshot` repeatedly requests the laptop password. Passwordless `ssh` is configured and apparently working correctly - I can `ssh` into the laptop both as root as well as the regular user.

How could passwordless `ssh` be properly configured yet be inaccessible to `rsnapshot` (rsync)?

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me to take a look at the actual `rsync` commands being executed. There, I discovered that `rsync` was attempting to `ssh` into my laptop not as root but as the regular user. Configuring PKE for this scenario solves the problem.